# Fit text into container (FLUTTER)

Tags: flutter, containers, padding, box, appbar

I wrapped my text into container and when I wanna use padding to move my container, I got this space.

**How can i fit text into container without any spaces anywhere.??**

```
appBar: AppBar(
        title: Container(
          child: Text(
            'MyAppBar',
            style:
                TextStyle(color: Colors.cyan[100], fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
          color: Colors.black,
        ),
),
```

Comment: what is not working the way you are expecting

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want space, just don't use padding and remove this line from your code;

```
padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 40),
```

Comment: so i want to move the text to right ,how can i do it ,without padding?????                                                   did you see my image i've  attached...?

Comment: You said that you did not want space, and now you want to move the text to right :) Can you describe your goal clearly, please.

Comment: I said that i wanna move my container with text , but when i used padding , my text moved instead whole container  and got that space i wish that would be clear.

Comment: So use margin instead of padding.